# Integrating passport authentication in lumen

Tags: api, lumen, laravel-passport

I am trying to integrate Passport authentication in Lumen (5.4.*) application using `dusterio/lumen-passport` https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport package.

I followed the steps till **Installed routes**, But when i try to access `/oauth/token` it throws 404 not found error

I am not sure what i am missing.

Can anyone help me out? Waiting for positive response.

Answer (score 2):

be sure to register passport route and register auth config in `bootstrap/app.php`

add

Edit config/auth.php to suit your needs. A simple example:

```
return [
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \Your\UserModel::class
    ]
]];
```

Load the config in bootstrap/app.php since Lumen doesn't load config files automatically:

```
$app->configure('auth');
```

and

```
Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport::routes($this->app);
```

Answer (score -2):

Although it is not recommended to edit vendor file , if you want I have a solution editing vendor file. Edit the below file as given below:

vendor/dusterio/lumen-passport/src/LumenPassport.php

Edit line 83 from

```
$callback->group(...
```

to

```
$callback->router->group(...
```